# CodeIgniter/PHP - Problema enviar dados do Model Para View

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, mvc

Boa noite,

Estou utilizando CodeIgniter 3.1.10. Estou com um problema em enviar um especifico dado do banco da Model para o Controller:

o var_dump($dados) me retorna apenas a array que eu passei que seria o email,

eu preciso que retorne os dados consultados do banco da coluna **verifica_key**

Como posso fazer isso?

o var_dump($teste); não me retorna nada...

**Model:**

```
public function reenvioSenha($dados) {

            $this->db->select("email,verifica_key");
            $this->db->from("usuarios");
            $this->db->where_in("email",$dados);

            $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
              foreach ($query->result() as $key => $value) {
                  $teste = $value->verifica_key;
              }

              return $teste;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
     public function reenviar_senha() {
     $dados = array (
        'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );
     if($this->Usuarios_model->reenvioSenha($dados) == true) {

                var_dump($dados);
                var_dump($teste);
                exit;
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar desta forma.

**controller**

```
public function reenviar_senha()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $this->load->model('usuario_model','usuario');
    $retorno = $this->usuario->reenviar_senha($email);
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //echo json_encode($retorno); //retorna em json
    print_r ($retorno);
}
```

**model**

```
public function reenviar_senha($email)
{       
    $this->db->select('*');
    //$this->db->select('email, verifica_key'); //caso queira consultar apenas os campos email e verifica_key
    $this->db->from('usuario');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $item = $query->result();

    return $item;
}
```